# Error occurs in url during express routing from a html button

Tags: javascript, html, express, backend

I run my home page from server localhost:3000 a button is supposed to redirect me to localhost:3000/register instead it redirects me to localhost:3000/register/  and an error shows as {"error":{"message":"Forbidden"}}

my backend route for register:

```
   var options={
   redirect:false
}

app.use(express.static('../..FRONT/REGISTER', options))

router.get('/register',(req,res,next)=>{
   res.sendFile(__dirname+ "../../FRONT/REGISTER/register.html")
})
```

button in home.html

```
  <a role="button" href="/register" class="btn btn-success mx-auto btn-lg">CREATE YOUR BLOG</a>
```

How can I solve this to render my register.html file and avoid this error

Comment: You're missing a slash in `app.use(express.static('../..FRONT/REGISTER', options))`... Should be `'../../FRONT/REGISTER'`.

Comment: I fixed it , still have same error

Comment: `__dirname` does not contain a trailing slash, so if you're trying to up a couple directories, you would need to change this: `res.sendFile(__dirname+ "../../FRONT/REGISTER/register.html")` to this: `res.sendFile(__dirname+ "/../../FRONT/REGISTER/register.html")`.  Or, even better, use `path.join()` when building paths so you can let it manage the slashes for you.